# Map subfolder of domain to azure app servive

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have our primary website [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) hosted on GoDaddy and its a WordPress website. We have now created a web app (MEAN stack app) and hosted it on azure app service. Its URL is  appname.azurewebsites.net.

We would like the azure app service to be domain.com/app. Is it possible for me to map domain.com/app (a subfolder of our primary domain on  GoDaddy) to the web app on azure app service.

After doing so; it should be like domain.com would load our WordPress website from GoDaddy and domain.com/app loads our web app from azure app service.

How do I accomplish this? Do I need to do some clever DNS settings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /app is part of the path, not the domain, so DNS has nothing to do here. What you could do, is put something like [Azure Front Door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/quickstart-create-front-door) (AFD) in front. You domain.com will be linked to that Front Door.

In AFD you can then define two backends, one for your main website and one for your App Service

Then you create two [routing rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-route-matching):

1. Your main website, with path `/*`
2. You web app with path `/app/*`